# Calculating copper losses of transformer given iron loss and maximum efficiency

Tags: power, transformer, loss

I wonder if anyone can help me understand copper losses in transformers a bit better.

I'm having problems understanding the highlighted part on the attached picture half way down the page. I sure its a simple maths thing which escapes me but why the \$\left( \frac{1}{0.80} \right)^2\$ ? Specifically, what's inside the brackets?

[image: Test Question]

Comment: Load power could be seen as a function of current, because the voltage doesn't change. But the copper loss has the variable voltage too, with the current, with the same changing proportion. You know, power is voltage * current. Then the power proportion would be its square because of same proportions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iron losses are 3 kW regardless of load. The copper losses are equal to the iron losses when the load (current) is 80% of full load. Since copper losses are proportional to the square of current, to scale up from 80% load to 100% load multiply the losses at 80% load by the square of the 100/80 increase in load.

Comment: Thank you Charles, I am nearly there. So if for example if the question asked for copper losses @30% load then what would go inside the brackets? (3/8)?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Transformer maximum efficiency occurs when the Iron losses (Fe Loss) are equal to the Copper Losses (Cu Loss). i.e. Cu Loss = I2R = 3kW = 3000 W

At max efficiency, transformer delivers 80% full load.

P=VI*cosØ

Transformer Parameters
V1/V2 = Vp/Vs = 440/110
Full load kVA = 40

1. S = VI
   I = S/V
   At full load, Ifl =40000/110 = 363.6364 A

At 80% full load, I0.8fl = 0.8*363.6364 = 290.9091 A

At max efficiency, R = 3000/I2 (Ω) = 3000/290.90912 = 0.03545 Ω

Cu Loss(@full load) = (Ifl)2 *R = 363.63642 * 0.03545 = 4.6875 kW ≈ 4.7 kW

2. Efficiency, η = (Pout/Pin)*100

Full load efficiency, ηfl = (Poutfl / Pinfl)*100
Poutfl = V*Ifl* cosØ = 110*363.6364*0.9 = 36000 W = 36 kW

Iron loss = 3 kW

Cu Loss(@full load) = 4.7 kW

Pinfl = Poutfl + Iron loss + Cu Loss(@full load) = 36 + 3 + 4.7 = 43.7 kW

ηfl = (Poutfl / Pinfl)*100 = (36/43.7)*100 = 82.38%

3. Efficiency @ 80% Full load, η0.8fl = (Pout0.8fl / Pin0.8fl)*100
   Pout0.8fl = V* I0.8fl * cosØ = 110*290.9091*1 = 32000 W = 32 kW

Iron loss = 3 kW

Cu Loss(@80%full load) = Iron loss = 3 kW

Pin0.8fl = Pout0.8fl + Iron loss + Cu Loss(@80%full load) = 32 + 3 + 3 = 38 kW

η0.8fl = (Pout0.8fl / Pin0.8fl)*100 = (32/38)*100 = 84.21%